# Json Schema autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, yaml, kubernetes-helm, json-schema-validator

Recently I have written Json schemas for the values.yaml files of the charts we are working on.

VSCode supports schema autocomplete.
My question is, does it exist some tools to subtract the already fulfilled elements of the schema and generate an another schema with the fields which were not satisfied? (subtract the default values file)